# Generic toArray<T> function which can call an init on the Type T

Tags: ios, swift

I have a struct called FlowerCategory as shown below:

```
struct FlowerCategory  {

    var id :Int?
    var title :String
    var imageURL :String



}

extension FlowerCategory {

    init?(node :Node) {

       // do something here 
    }
}
```

I am creating an extension on the Node class which will convert the node into a strongly typed class array. The problem is that I cannot invoke the T.init initializer as shown below:

```
extension Node {

    func toArray<T>() -> [T]? {

        guard let nodes = self.nodeArray else {
            return nil
        }

        return nodes.flatMap(T.init) // This will NOT work
    }

}
```

Is there anyway to do what I am trying to achieve?

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: What is `Node`?

Comment: How about replacing T.init with T() or T()! ?

Comment: @ppalancica That did not work. I updated the code in the above question.

Comment: Well the problem is that the compiler knows nothing about the type `T` – but in any case, it doesn't really seem like it's worth an extension in the first place, why not just say `someNode.nodeArray?.flatMap(FlowerCategory.init)`?

Comment: Because it looks ugly and I want to make it better :)